# How do I launch the WebSphere management console in Windows 2003 Server

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1

I am new to WebSphere application server. I need to make minor changes on the server.
I don't know how to launch the Admin console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the default ports are used you can access the console from http://localhost:9060/ibm/console